# Lower page number for selected pages

Tags: floats, page-numbering, koma-script

Is there a possibility to lower the page number at a single page where a large figure (float) with a height nearly pageheight is positioned?
So the command must probably be used inside the figure environment?
How can that easily be achieved in the KOMA classes?

Here an example:
First Page with the large figure and where the page number should be lowered to be below the figure, second Page with small figure and usual/normal position of page number

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=24cm]{name}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{name}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a fully compilable (minimum working) example to your post by editing it? It would help the solvers a lot.

Comment: You mean that a page with a large figure is not counted at all?

Comment: No, the position of the page number should be lowered

Comment: I think it's more usual to instead have pagestyle empty on those pages. (So you'll have to look at some page before or after to know the page number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the pagestyle to `empty` for just that page, then you can add the page number into the figure using `\thepage`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=24cm]{name}\\
\thepage
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{name}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Lowered page number in figure]

Note that I'm not recommending this. I would tend to omit the page number altogether on this page as others indicated in the comments. Nonetheless, this is how I would do it if I wanted to have it this way...